# Xorg stuck with got pause for 226:0

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gnome-shell, gpu

After a I run startx, some text is printed and then instead of changing to gnome it gets stuck at the tty. However if I run with wayland, everything works.

The tail of the log:

```
...
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
[    71.564] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
[    71.565] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
[    71.565] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
```

My system:

```
Linux 5.4.2-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 05 Dec 2019 12:29:40 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo GP108M [GeForce MX150]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```